# Displaying smile emoticon inside text view

Tags: java, android

How can I display smile emoticon inside TextView? Are there any special Android libraries for this purpose or I must embed this emoticon by Unicode characters in format \uXXXX?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

In my unicode I replaced 'U+' by '0x'

Example: replace 'U+1F60A' by '0x1F60A'

This way I got an 'int' like

```
int unicode = 0x1F60A;
```

Which can be used with

```
public String getEmojiByUnicode(int unicode){ return new String(Character.toChars(unicode)); }
```

So Textview displays  without Drawable

Try it with http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode